# MySQL string contains only certain unicode characters

Tags: mysql, regex, unicode

I need to query the database for entries that contain only a certain set of Unicode Japanese characters and nothing else.

I've tried using `WHERE word RLIKE '^([あいうえお])+$'` but that doesn't work with Japanese because of lack of Unicode support in MySQL's regex.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287145/mysql-querying-for-unicode-entities

Comment: That only fixes LIKE, not RLIKE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL is looking at each character as a byte sequence, so `あ` is 0xE3, 0x81, 0x82 and your `[あいうえお]` is actually looking for any sequence of bytes 0xE3, 0x81, 0x82, 0x84, 0x86, 0x88 and 0x8A. That will match `あ` fine, but it will also match other sequences that don't correspond to a single character in the list, for example 0xE3, 0x82, 0x81 which is `め`.

An alternative way of saying `[あいうえお]` that would still work when each character is considered by the regex engine as being more than one symbol would be `(あ|い|う|え|お)`.

```
SELECT 'あ' RLIKE '^([あいうえお])+$';    -- 1
SELECT 'め' RLIKE '^([あいうえお])+$';    -- 1
SELECT 'あ' RLIKE '^(あ|い|う|え|お)+$';  -- 1
SELECT 'め' RLIKE '^(あ|い|う|え|お)+$';  -- 0
```