# Hidden character in Pages and MySql

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a text that seems that have a hidden character.

The original text was written with Apple Pages, the word processor, and copy-paste to a MySql database. They are h2 written with markdown. I detected that hidden character when I make a SELECT to the database to output the `## (.*)` space and convert to h2 tag. Some of them work and some do not. For instance, if I use /## / (with a space behind #) regex only finds ## Brand:

```
## Brand
## New Tech
```

I tested that in different regex tools. For instance: http://regexr.com/3f660 They all find only `## Brand`. with `/## /`

I can solve the problem if I use `##\s` or just delete that space and make a space again. I have many cases like that in a big database and I would like to understand first and clean it later. If I go to Apple Pages > Show Invisibles it shows `:` between # and N in ## New Tech. What is that character and how can I find id to delete it in a MySql database?

Comment: It is a [non-breaking space, `\xA0`](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%C2%A0#title).

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew: do you know how to find that in a MySql database?

Comment: @Nrc see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287145/mysql-querying-for-unicode-entities).