# Find non-breaking space in MySql

Tags: mysql

How can I find a non-breaking space in a MySql database?

For instance between # and N:

```
## New Tech
```

I tried to select the table and click to query:

```
UPDATE test 
SET text = replace (text, "&nbsp;", "")
WHERE id = 3;
```

It finds 0 results and I am sure there is

With regex I can use also:

```
\xA0
```

But I do not know how to apply that in a MySql database

Comment: 1) `&nbsp;` doesn't have any special meaning except in the context of HTML. Are you looking for an actual space or its HTML entity? 2) The only WHERE condition is on column `id`. Spaces have nothing to do with matches.

Comment: @Alvaro: it is a hidden character that comes from Apple Pages. See my previous question here with more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935301/hidden-character-in-pages-and-mysql

Answer (score 23):

Non-breaking spaces are often encoded as C2A0 (in hex), so you could try:

```
update test set text = replace(text, UNHEX('C2A0'),'')
```

Answer (score 0):

UNIHEX did not help. Instead I used CHAR(160) and it worked -

```
UPDATE <table_name> 
SET 
    <column_name> = REPLACE(<column_name>, CHAR(160), ' ');
```

The above query will replace non-breaking space with a normal space. You can make changes according to your need.