# How can i search strange characters in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, encode

I have a problem with the search on my site. I have a search input to find products by name. If I type 'leña' (the problem is the strange characters).

This is in the controller

```
 $termino = $_POST['search']);
 $locale = LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale(); //es in this case
 $products = Product::where('title', 'LIKE', "%\"{$locale}\":%{$termino}%");
```

This is the content of the field 'title' in the database.

```
{"es":"PAN DE LE\u00d1A"}
```

The search returns 0 results.

I am sure the problem is the codification and I don´t know how to resolve it.

The codification is utf8mb4.

Thanks

Comment: That is an escaped unicode representation, common in json, is that really how it's stored in the database?

Comment: Thanks for tour answers. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287145/mysql-querying-for-unicode-entities)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply encode the string before performing the query, e.g:

```
// assuming that $termino is a string 
// json_encode should return the unicode representation
$search = json_encode($termino);

// I changed the where condition a bit, 
// but your own condition is also do fine
$products = Product::where('title->'.$locale, 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not really lie on non-English characters. The root issue is that you store a complex data format (JSON) in a single database cell, as opposed to designing your database to hold the individual pieces of data:

```
create table product_title (
    product_id int(10) not null,
    locale varchar(2) not null,
    title varchar(200),
    primary key (product_id, locale)
);
insert into product_title (product_id, locale, title) values (1, 'es', 'Leña');
insert into product_title (product_id, locale, title) values (1, 'en', 'Wood');
```

You have a relational database but you haven't designed it around your data structure, so you cannot use most of its features, inclusing basic stuff like `WHERE` or `ORDER BY`.

You can fix the design (please, do) or apply a workaround:

- If you have a recent MySQL version, you can make the column of [`JSON` type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html).
- You can create two versions of your JSON data and expect that database values do not have mixed cases:

  ```
  $locale = 'es';
  $termino = 'Leña';
  $data = [
      $locale => ":%{$termino}%"
  ];
  $ascii = json_encode($data);
  $unicode = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

  // Use your framework's syntax instead:
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM product WHERE title IN (:ascii, :unicode)';
  $params = [$ascii, $unicode];
  ```

Please note there's no sane workaround to use LIKE wildcards too.