# How to deal with JSON encoded string in MySQL REPLACE Statement

Tags: sql, replace, utf-8, character-encoding, mariadb

I have this string in some MariaDB Column (let's called it MY_COL):
`{"libelle": "com\u00e9dien"}` that i'd like to replace it with
`{"libelle": "acteur"}`

Using this [STO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287145/mysql-querying-for-unicode-entities), I figured out how to select rows containing this string:

```
SELECT MY_COL
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MY_COL LIKE '%{"libelle": "com\\\\u00e9dien%'
```

But, when I used this "over-sized escaping" technic in an UPDATE Statement, it doesn't work

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET MY_COL = REPLACE(MY_COL, '{"libelle": "com\\\\\\u00e9dien"', '{"libelle": "acteur"')
```

Nevertheless, I noticed that this SELECT statement works well:

```
SELECT '{"libelle": "com\\\\\\u00e9dien"' As `Column_Before`,
REPLACE('{"libelle": "com\\\\\\u00e9dien"', '{"libelle": "com\\\\\\u00e9dien"', '{"libelle": "acteur"') As `Column_After`;
```

[image]

It seems that referring to the Column_Name in the REPLACE statement leads to this issue but I don't know why nor do I know how to prevent that.

Last info: the table, the column and the database use UTF8MB4 encoding with utf8mb4_general_ci collation.

I use DBeaver (latest version) and MariaDB's version is 10.8.6

Comment: Please can you share a sample from an example value of `MY_COL` that should be replaced, but is not?  (NB I note that your first test does not include the closing double quote `"` - perhaps that is significant)

Comment: The example value of MyCol is for instance:
[{"libelle": "com\u00e9dien", "precision indexation": null, "reference": 10453708}, {"libelle": "s\u00e9rie t\u00e9l\u00e9vis\u00e9e", "precision indexation": null, "reference": 10500327}]

Comment: Establish the connection as being utf8 and use `é` instead of `U+00E9`

Comment: Thanks @RickJames It's a work around but not the expected answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [proper JSON functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-functions/)

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET MY_COL = JSON_SET(MY_COL, '$.libelle', 'acteur')
WHERE JSON_VALUE(MY_COL, '$.libelle') = 'comédien';
```

If you have an array of such objects you can unnest them in a subquery, change what needs to be changed and reaggregate.

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET MY_COL = (
    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
      JSON_OBJECT('libelle',
        CASE WHEN j.libelle = 'comédien'
             THEN 'acteur'
             ELSE j.libelle
             END
        )
      )
    FROM JSON_TABLE(MY_COL, '$[0]' columns (
        libelle varchar(100) path '$.libelle'
    )) AS j
);
```

Comment: First query works but returned 0 updated rows.

Second query doesn't work:  check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')) AS j)' at line 13

Comment: Sorry missed off the path, fixed now. If you have an array then version 1 won't work as I said.

Comment: Another solution which works: 
```UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET MY_COL = JSON_REPLACE(MY_COL,"$[0].libelle","acteur")
```

Comment: That's similar to my first answer, but only replaces a single value, not a whole array

Comment: I found another solution to replace a value no matter what key it's linked to.
```UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET MY_COL = JSON_REPLACE(MY_COL , JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(MY_COL , "all", "comédien")), 'acteur')```
With:
```JSON_SEARCH(MY_COL , "all", "comédien")``` found the key anywhere in the JSON string,
```JSON_UNQUOTE``` is used to use the found key in the ```JSON_REPLACE```